# adding search field to listView wrecked my code

Tags: android, listview, search, android-activity

im having a problem that I guess its a simple solution, but i can't figure it out...

I have an activity with a listview and a search field, when i click on an item, it loads a new view with a content relative to what was clicked...

Anyway, it all worked out fine, BUT, now that i added the search field, It's not working anymore...

I figured out the problem, but i can't understand what i should replace it to...

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString(); //PROBLEM

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BotafogoSingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          i.putExtra("product", product);
          startActivity(i);

      }
    });
```

this guy `String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();` is the problem..

When i look at the debug panel, this is what i get:
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.LinearLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView

I'm guessing that this line is getting the Linear Layout instead of the TextView that it's inside?

Answer (score 1):

`OnItemClick`'s `view` parameter is the view of the entire list item. In this case, it looks like you moved from using a single TextView for each list_item to using a custom LinearLayout (which I assume contains your TextView).

In this case, you'd want to replace your product line with

```
String product = ((TextView) view.findById(R.id.your_text_view)).
    getText().toString();
```

Where your_text_view is the android:id associated with the TextView.

Comment: IT WORKED! Thanks ianhanniballake

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solves your problem and good luck going forward!